# Messed up with two python versions on linux

Tags: python, linux

As I understood, I have two versions of python 2.7 installed on my machine. One is located in `/usr/bin` and another one is in `/usr/local/bin`. When I type python in the shell, it calls one in `/usr/local/bin`, and it doesn't have access to all the packages installed using `apt-get` and pip. I have tried to set up an alias, but when I type `sudo python` it still calls one in `/usr/local/bin`. I want to always use one in `/usr/bin`, since I have all the packages there. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome! it isn't a problem, check the https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: ask this question on  https://unix.stackexchange.com  you will surely get answer their.

Comment: Could you indicate the OS distribution and version, such as ubuntu 17.04 ?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you delete the one in /local but this is not really a solution if it makes it run the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood,

1. You have two version of python. One is in /usr/local/bin/python
   and another is in /usr/bin/python.
2. In your current configuration default python ->
   /usr/local/bin/python
3. You want to use the one that is in /usr/bin.

Update your ~/.bashrc and append this line at the end

`alias python=/usr/bin/python`

Then open a new terminal. Or do `source ~/.bashrc` in the current terminal

Run `which python` to see the location of the python executable. It will show you /usr/bin/python

---

Also, if you want to get packages in your current python (i.e. /usr/local/bin/python) you can use pip with that particular python version.

1. Find pip location using `which pip`
2. Assuming pip location is /usr/local/bin/pip
   /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pip install

Answer (score 0):

you can easily have two python version in your machine. 
But first I recommend to [install](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) the Anaconda package.

And then you can create an environment with python 3 version

```
conda create --name test_env python=3 numpy pandas
```

In order to activate it, you need to write in your terminal

```
source activate test_env
```

More info here:
https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html